# How to declare UIImageView with SDWebImage

Tags: objective-c

I just added to my project SDWebImage but I really can't understand how to use the following method:

```
[cell.img setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

but I get the error:

```
No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:'
```

I added the header:

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

and declared the img as UIImageView, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see every method of the category UIImageView (WebCache) has prefix "sd_", so you should use method sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:   instead of setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:.